# Where is Sign In View located for Devise- Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

This might be a stupid question, but my Sign In view looks like total crap and isn't roping in any of the CSS styles from the other pages.

For whatever reason, I cannot find this view to even edit it. The only folders in my views are posts, pages, and layout. Does anyone know how I can go about editing what the sign in view looks like?

my route.rb:

```
Projectmadrone::Application.routes.draw do
   mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

  resources :posts
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me


  has_many :posts
 end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to run the generator for devise views, this will copy them to your app (they live in the gem by default):

```
rails g devise:views
```

There's more info about configuring the views here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Make sure you use and leverage and style the views provided for you for users to register and edit their accounts.  See app/views/devise/registrations  Don't write your own. Use these provided ones.